# whether there are hidden dangers of my custom memory allocator

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, game-engine, allocator

Recently, I was writing a custom memory allocator，See this article in detail [custom memeory alloc..](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13705427/1875598)

thanks to the answer of [David Hammen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13705994/1875598)，now i can free the memory of polymorphic objects correctly. then seem i can use **MYNEW** macro to alloc memory and construct object, use **MYDEL** macro to destroy object and free memory，also can be memory tracking.

but I'm not sure whether it can be used in a complex project environment（eg:complex multiple inheritance design..), whether there are hidden dangers ?

NOTE: i am not ask for how to do memory manager, how to overload operator new/delete(global or for class), I just want to know whether there are problem of this method in the actual project development. Thanks for any answer.

Comment: imo, "custom memory allocator" is automatically dangerous.

Comment: Why are you doing a custom memory allocator instead of using the default?  (There are multiple reasons, I want to know which apply to you.)  If you need STL to use your allocator, then you need to define a std::allocate<> type template.

Comment: @brian beuning for two reason: 1. alloc tracking. 2. manage memory allocator. eg:use nedalloc lib to optimize new/delete on win-xp os.
as you said, when i need STL custom allocator, i will define a STLAllocator template, but also use MYNEW/MYDEL to alloc/dealloc memory inner.

Comment: This question asks for discussion. There is no definitive answer. Probably should be closed.

Comment: Why not have a look at Google's tcmalloc from gperftools (http://code.google.com/p/gperftools/)? It even allows you to profile your code easily. It kind of acts as a garbage collection for small object allocation.

Comment: before I forget, with tcmalloc you only need to link to it and it automatically starts using it. Ofcourse, it depends on your need. For some applications you will see a performance improvements, for others you won't